# Hide parameters in Swagger + Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger

I'm developing an application with Spring Boot 2 + Swagger 3 please find Swagger dependencies below

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have multiple Rest controller one method can find below

```
@PostMapping(value = "/del", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Flux<Map<String, Object delete(@ApiParam(required = true, value = "file name(s) to delete") @RequestBody Flux<String> files) {
       .........
}
```

But in Swagger UI it showing other parameters too. How to hide all these extra parameters (formData, query) except actual parameter (files).

[image]

Comment: Use '@ApiParam' like '@ApiParam(value = " country", hidden = true)'

Comment: In UI showing multiple parameters (30+), annotating all these params may take more time. Is there any other way

Comment: @soorapadman no luck not working

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm having the same problem now but I'm passing Errors through.

Answer (score 1):

When configuring docket, an option is available to provide class definitions to ignore.

```
 @Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .ignoredParameterTypes(Authentication.class)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.withClassAnnotation(RestController.class))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
```

**Note:** `.ignoredParameterTypes(Authentication.class)` where *Authentication.class* refers to *org.springframework.security.core.Authentication*.  Helpfull when injecting various contexts into controller methods which are irrelevant to the api user.